# Prohibit viewdidload on subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, viewdidload

I have this myViewController, that instantiates instances of itself.

Currently, I have a UIButton, that triggers the method

```
-(void)somethingImportant
```

However, I want that **somethingImportant** to happen during the ViewDidLoad, so I don't have to push that button.

But if I put  **somethingImportant** in the **ViewDidLoad** of myViewController, it is recursively called as many times I have a subview of myViewController.

I tried to put **somethingImportant** in the **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** of my app delegate, but somehow that does't work either.

**EDIT**

So here's the code that might be relevant. I have this UIScrollView with a lot of subviews  of myViewController:

```
- (void)configureScrollView
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
        ...
        myViewController * theSubview =[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
       ....
        [theScrollView addSubview:[theSubview view]];
    }

}
```

What is the best approach to make sure that **somethingImportant** is called only once?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do here. Is your view controller that manages your child `myViewController` objects of type `myViewController`? That still inherently smells of recursion.

Comment: Well, yes. OT: recursion is cool. However, the recursion only starts happening when  the method is called from viewDidLoad. Before that, everything is just dandy. So, I was hoping that there is a simple trick to bypass that.  Something like "ViewDidLoadForTheFirstTime"

Comment: if view -> aweakFromNib
if viewController -> viewDidLoad

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a method of `UIViewController`, not of `UIView`.  I realize you do understand this, but your wording is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this class, that instantiates instances of itself.

This inherently sounds like a bad idea and can easily lead to recursion if you're not careful. Therefore I would suggest you rethink your logic. If you need multiple instances of a class, you should be managing those instances from outside that class, not from within.

However, if you're still insistent on doing this - you can do something similar to what [sschale suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022814/2976878) and use a variable to keep track of whether you've called your method or not.

The thing is you'll need to define this variable as `static` in order for it to be stored at *class* scope, not instance scope.

**For example:**

```
static BOOL firstCalled = NO;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!firstCalled) {
        firstCalled = YES;
        [self foo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe I don't express myself correctly. In my myViewController, I have a method that does 
- (void)whatever
{ myViewController * theSubview;
[theScrollView addSubview:[theSubview view]];
}

Comment: I ended up creating a masterViewController, to get rid of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Each subclass should be calling `[super viewDidLoad]`, on up the chain, so that code really should only be called once.

However, if you need to make sure it executes only once, add `@property (nonatomic) BOOL runOnce;` to that file's interface, and then in `-(viewDidLoad)` do:

```
if(!self.runOnce) {
    //all code that is only run once
    self.runOnce = YES;
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you propose. But it didn't work. To see what's going on, I inserted "NSLog(runOnce ? @"Yes" : @"No");" just before the "if(!runOnce) {" line in viewDidLoad. My console said no, as many times as I have subviews.

Comment: No you're supposed to put that code inside of the `if` loop.

Comment: It's outside the loop.